# Selection of table (or view) in oracle, that I cannot find in TOAD

Tags: oracle, naming

I am reverse-engineering an application which administers an Oracle database.
Everything is new to me (application + database)
There is a statement there somewhere, which is:

`SELECT * FROM XXX@YYY` (XXX is a word, YYY another word)

If I go into my database with TOAD I can't find an 'XXX@YYY' table nor view. If I copy paste the statement in TOAD's editor, I get results as if the table exists.

- I know that the '@' symbol is allowed for naming an Oracle object. Is it possible that it means something else here though?
- How can I find the table (or view)? Is it possible to get information through a statement such as which schema does 'XXX@YYY' belong to or weather it is a table or a view, so that I can track it?
- The database consists of many schemas. There is a default one. Is it possible that XXX@YYY may belong to another schema, rather than the default?

Please help me find the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Identifier behind @ is database link. It is a way to access objects on some remote Oracle server. more info on http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_5005.htm#SQLRF01205

Answer (score 1):

In Toad/Oracle XXX@YYY means object@database_link.
Look for the schema in your DB, there you will find the table.
Btw: I think its better to use SCHEMA.TABLENAME

If you have problems finding the SCHEMA, go to View->Toad Options, select Treeview at Browser style and then it should display all schemas.

Comment: I cannot find a YYY schema either. YYY has a word DBL in it's name though, meaning database link, namely XXX@DBL_YYY. Am I missing something here?

Comment: "Toad/Oracle XXX@YYY means TABLENAME@SCHEMA." -- I don't think that this is true.

Comment: Uh im sorry, your true, wrote to fast. Its SCHEMA@DATABASE. Will edit the answer.

Comment: Actually it's object@database_link -- could be a view or synonym pl/sql object.

Comment: Ah okay, allways thought its Schema@DB. Thx ;)